# How do I find a specific delayed job (not by id)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, delayed-job

Delayed::Job serializes your class, method & parameters into the handler field.  We currently resort to hardcoding this serialized method into our code.  This is gross.

How should we be constructing the handler so we can look up an existing queued up job?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish that looking up by ID won't do? Why do you need to look up a job after it's been queued for work?

Comment: We queue up jobs to run in 10 minutes for example.  If something changes and we need to delete that job, how do we get a handle on it? The request five minutes later has no idea what the id was when the last when was scheduled.

Comment: Hmm, yeah. That is a mess. I would lean toward storing the job_id + foo_model_id in a separate table for easier lookup. Then make an evil twin for either `Delayed::Job#invoke_job` or `Delayed::Job#run_with_lock` to perform some cleanup. Or even better, add a cleanup callback so that this can get reused.

Answer (score 16):

This what I do:

**1) Add two new columns to `delayed_jobs` table**

db/migrations/20110906004963_add_owner_to_delayed_jobs.rb

```
class AddOwnerToDelayedJobs < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    add_column :delayed_jobs, :owner_type, :string
    add_column :delayed_jobs, :owner_id, :integer

    add_index :delayed_jobs, [:owner_type, :owner_id]
  end

  def self.down
    remove_column :delayed_jobs, :owner_type
    remove_column :delayed_jobs, :owner_id
  end
end
```

**2) Add a polymorphic association to `Delayed::Job` model**

config/initializers/delayed_job.rb

```
class Delayed::Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :owner, :polymorphic => true
  attr_accessible :owner, :owner_type, :owner_id
end
```

**3) Monkey patch `ActiveRecord::Base` to contain a jobs association**

config/initializers/active_record.rb

```
class ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :jobs, :class_name => "Delayed::Job", :as => :owner
  def send_at(time, method, *args)
    Delayed::Job.transaction do
      job = Delayed::Job.enqueue(Delayed::PerformableMethod.new(self, 
             method.to_sym, args), 10, time)
      job.owner = self
      job.save
    end
  end

  def self.jobs
    # to address the STI scenario we use base_class.name. 
    # downside: you have to write extra code to filter STI class specific instance.
    Delayed::Job.find_all_by_owner_type(self.base_class.name)
  end
end
```

**4) Triggering a jobs**

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base

  after_create :set_reminders

  def set_reminders
    send_at(2.days.from_now, :send_email_reminder)
  end

  def send_email_reminder
  end

  # setting owner for handle_asynchronously notation.
  def foo
  end
  handle_asynchronously :foo, :owner => Proc.new { |o| o  }

end
```

**5) Inspecting jobs**

```
Order.jobs  # lists all the running jobs for Order class
order1.jobs # lists all the running jobs for Order object order1
```

Comment: do you know if you could use the handle_asynchronously line to set the values in the new columns?  I'm trying to have the system carry the db:schema that was active when the job was created with the job, so it can be set when the job starts.

Comment: @daveatflow I have updated the answer. Take a look. Make sure you take note of the `attr_accessible` portion of the monkey patch.

Comment: You can avoid **step (3)** by restricting the association to the objects you want to be linked to `Delayed::Job`. You can do so following [this steps](http://sunilkumarn.wordpress.com/2013/05/19/delayed-jobs-in-rails-adding-custom-attributes/)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply but thanks, awesome stuff !
Although I would probably not monkey patch active_jobs initializer, I would put all of this in a module/concern and include it in the models that use this !