# uninitialized constant ActiveRecord::Base::Delayed::Job

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to add an owner field to DelayedJob. I found this [SO answer showing a way to do it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7327175/382818)

But when I code things up like mentioned in that answer, and in the rails console I do

```
SomeArModel.new.jobs
```

I get this error:

`NameError: uninitialized constant ActiveRecord::Base::Delayed::Job`

The error points to the `has_many`:

```
class ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :jobs, :class_name => "Delayed::Job", :as => :owner
  ....
```

Any ideas on what is going on here and how I can fix it?